# cordova angular cannot connect to socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, socket.io

My `Ionic` is working with `socket.io` in a webview. But when I try to compile my app to android, it seems that `socket.io` cannot connect to my `nodejs` server.

As I console everything to my node server for connection events, it doesn't trigger the `connection` event as seen below:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('My socket id is '+socket.id);
});
```

My node console works properly when I try to run the app in a browser. But using the android app extracted from cordova it seems it cannot connect.

UPDATE: this is my `config.xml` file in my app

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.pagemanager" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>PageManager</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Are you using Ionic?

Comment: Are you using `socket.io-client` as your dependency? Have you whitelisted your server domain (e.g. have a look into cordova docs for [whitelisting](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html))?

Comment: @DevidFarinelli yes

Comment: @Beat I already tried allow access all, it seems my socket io client connects because it returns an object but my on connection event in `node` is not being triggered

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app on your device? Do you get any error?

Comment: @DevidFarinelli the problem is i dont know how to debug in app

Comment: You can follow [these](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) steps to debug your android app using chrome dev tools, and if you need further help just update your question with the messages you get from the console :)

Comment: @DevidFarinelli thank you. btw the debugging is only available for chrome mobile app? because i tried viewing my app on web mobile app and its working fine i got socket id for current tab. how about debugging the produced app by cordova, the apk one.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you misunderstood, following that steps and connecting your phone through USB, you can debug the `apk` installed on your phone using Chrome's dev tools from you PC.
PS: You can do the same for your iOS app using Safari ([guide](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787))

Comment: @DevidFarinelli i cannot connect my device to chrome :( i already turn on usb debugging but chrome cant detect

Comment: 1) Enable usb debugging on your device  2) run `adb devices` in a terminal window on your PC 3) click ok to an alert appeared on your phone
After this you should be able to see your device in chrome, let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: @DevidFarinelli thank you. i need to download sdk first. because in google instruction they didnt require sdk just download usb driver turn on usb debuging and thats all and have it check on chrome->inspect->more tools->devices. i wanted to talk to you more about this ionic thing. thank you so much for the help. i will update this when i connected already my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solved my problem. what i did is to make it work in a simulator so that i can debug or see easily the errors. and i fount out the the path in mobile is always starting in `file://` blah blah when i use the native script code to get current path. and thats why its not connecting to my Nodejs Server. and everything is fixed now. thank you! SO'ers.